# How to correctly represent a nested sum

Tags: summation

Suppose I have a matrix:

$$
        A = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 4 & 7 \\
        2 & 5 & 8 \\
        3 & 6 & 9 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
For which i want to sum the elements.

My first inclination is to write:

$$ \sum_j \sum_i A_{i,j} $$

But I am unsure whether this is normally read:

$$ \sum_j \left( \sum_i A_{i,j} \right) $$

Or:

$$ \left(\sum_j \sum_i \right) A_{i,j}  $$

Where i intend the latter.

Comment: The latter notation means nothing. The former is what you want. First you sum the rows. Then you sum the row sums. This works by associativity of addition.

Comment: OK, you beat me by 1 minute but I posted it as an answer. Sorry! :(

Comment: An alternative: $$\sum_{i,j}A_{i,j}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter notation is meaningless. The first one is correct. However, without the parentheses, it means the same thing. The last one is the big no-no. In other words: $$ \sum_j \sum_i A_{i,j} \equiv \sum_j \left( \sum_i A_{i,j} \right), $$ but you should **not** write $$ \left( \sum_j \sum_i \right) A_{i,j}. $$